# Whitespace as wide as a character

Tags: spacing, color

I would like to produce whitespace as wide as a particular character. One trick I have figured out is to use `{\color{white} x}` (if for example this would produce whitespace as wide as the character x) with the color package. However, this is problematic, as when I create a `pdf` (e.g. using `pdflatex`), the character will still be there, so that if a user copies some text they have selected including the "invisible" character, they will also copy that character. Are there better methods to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way seems to be `\phantom{CHARACTERHERE}`

**EDIT:**
A slightly fancier way is to create a new length:

```
\newlength{\characterlength}
\settowidth{\characterlength}{CHARACTERHERE}
```

then use

```
\hspace{\characterlength}
```

Comment: `\phantom` also produces vertical white space (though, most times this will not matter). For only horizontal white space, use `\hphantom`, for vertical, `\vphantom`.