# Whitespace characters

Tags: white-space

I am defining a command that uses an subscript somewhere. I want the subscript to dissappear when I leave its corresponding command-input open, but then LaTeX will trow an error since no character was put in the subscript. Now I want to type a dummy character after the input to ensure that at least one character is printed at all times. However, I don't want this dummy character to show up. It just needs to be there to decieve LaTeX.

If I type \infty, I get an infinity symbol, if I print the character I am asking for, LaTeX prints a character that has no black.

---

In this code, the command \spacechar takes the role of the character I want

```
\newcommand{\tup}[3]{(-\; #1 -\! \underset{\! #2 \,\,\,}{)_{#3\spacechar}}}
```

instead of

```
\newcommand{\tup}[3]{(-\; #1 -\! \underset{\! #2 \,\,\,}{)_{#3}}}
```

which breaks when #3 is empty.

Some example of the code in action

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\tup}[3]{(-\; #1 -\! \underset{\! #2 \,\,\,}{)_{#3}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent $\tup{x_i}{i}{n}$\\
$(-\; x_i -\! \underset{\!  \,\,\,}{)}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Versions of the command]

---

Something like this is also useful in many other places where LaTeX, such as when LaTeX wants to remove whitespace at the beginning of a sentence.

This is a slightly related but unsatisfying answer. 
[Whitespace as wide as a character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124860/whitespace-as-wide-as-a-character) It gives whitespace commands, which are not actual characters. They are whitespace, and whitespace can't decieve LaTeX.

This is also not what I'm looking for. [Explicit space character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50804/explicit-space-character) Instead of invisible characters it gives me visible whitespace.

In short, I want a character that prints absolutely nothing.

Comment: Welcome.  It would help if you posted some code, so that we could see the context.  In general `$a_{}$` works just fine.

Comment: Your question isn't clear (to me, at least). If I understand correctly, you want braces after the subscript, so that either `a_{}` or `a_{b}` will work.

Comment: It's better if you show your attempt and example of use.

Comment: I have included some code

Comment: You probably want to have a look at `xparse` and all of its goodies of parsing arguments, graping subscripts etc.

Comment: I see, when arg `#3` is absent, it compiles, but moves `#2` relative to the closing paren.  What is it you actually want when `#3` is missing?

Comment: what do you mean by "breaks when empty" ? `_{}` is not an error?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True. It does work now, for some reason. I think I made a typo in my file and corrected it here, and fixed it while playing around with it.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem in using `\underset` is that it tries to center the underset material.  You want the underset to be left aligned with the paren, if I understand your intentions.  To do that, I use a left-aligned stack.

Here, I show the 4 cases where `#2` and `#3` are either present or absent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\tup}[3]{(-\; #1 -\! 
  \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{1pt}{)_{#3}}{\scriptstyle#2}{U}{l}{F}{F}{S}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent $\tup{x_i}{i}{n}$\\[4pt]
$\tup{x_i}{i}{}$\\[4pt]
$\tup{x_i}{}{n}$\\[4pt]
$\tup{x_i}{}{}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it does make it better.

Comment: @NielsKorpel You can upvote the answer if you like it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a “`\spacechar`”.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\tup}[3]{%
  ({-}\; #1 \;{-}%
  \mathclose{\underset{\mathclap{#2\,}}{)}}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax\else
    \mathclose{}_{#3}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

$\tup{x_i}{i}{n}$

$\tup{x_i}{i}{}$

\end{document}
```

With `\underset{\mathclap{#1\,}{)}` we set the argument below the parentheses, making the whole construction a Close atom; *if* the third argument is not empty, a phantom parentheses receives the subscript.

[image]

I also propose a friendlier syntax, where the subscript is specified with the standard `_`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tup}{mme{_}}{%
  ({-}\; #1 \;{-}
  \mathclose{\underset{\mathclap{#2\,}}{)}}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{\mathclose{\vphantom)}_{#3}}%
}


\begin{document}

$\tup{x_i}{i}_{n}$

$\tup{x_i}{i}$

\end{document}
```

Similarly, but with also the second argument optional, in case you sometimes need no variable below the parenthesis.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tup}{mme{_}}{%
  ({-}\; #1 \;{-}
  \mathclose{\underset{\mathclap{#2\,}}{)}}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{\mathclose{\vphantom)}_{#3}}%
}


\begin{document}

$\tup{x_i}{i}_{n}$

$\tup{x_i}{i}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The definition in the question is correct and does not break. I presume I made forgot the braces in the actual file. The above answer from @Steven B. Segletes does make the command better.

However, as for my question on invisible characters, I have found an imperfect solution.

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\spacechar}{\text{\textcolor{white}{\tiny .}}}
```

This will print a tiny white dot, which works so long as the background isn't white.

Comment: why would you ever want a coloured `.` ? not say a thin space like `\,` or nothing? I don't think this is really an answer to the question as asked. If you turned on tracing to see how much work tex does to evaluate `\text{\textcolor{white}{\tiny .}` you would see several hundred lines, `\text` evaluates its argument four times, and `\tiny` loads an entire font setup, `\textcolor` inserts additional colour whatsits....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle why `\text` evaluates its argument four times? I don't understand. Thank you!

Comment: @manooooh https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110637/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I still do not understand. What does `\mathchoice` command have to do with `\text`?

Comment: @manooooh the difference between mbox and text is just that text uses mathchoice so it is smaller in subscripts

Answer (score 0):

With `xparse` optional arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \otup { m O{} O{} }{
    (-\; #1 -\! \underset{\tl_if_empty:nTF{#3}{}{\!} #2 \,\,\,}{\tl_if_empty:nTF{#3}{\!\!}{})\sb{#3}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
$\otup{x_i}[i][n]$

$\otup{x_i}[i]$

$\otup{x_i}$

\end{document}
```

This does not use the `stackengine` solution of the other answer, instead when the 3rd argument is empty (not given) then the right parenthesis is shifted back a bit, if the argument is not empty then the underset argumentitself (`#2`) is shifted left.

Note that with `\ExplSyntaxOn` the `_` character is no longer a math subscript, so `\sb` is used instead.

[image]